# Querying an NSDictionary for values in an if/else statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

My parse cloud code function is setup to return data in the form of JSON, like so:

```
response.success
({
                "results": [
                  { "Number of top categories": top2.length },
                            { "Top categories": top2 },  
                         { "Number of matches": userCategoriesMatchingTop2.length }, 
         { "User categories that match search": userCategoriesMatchingTop2 }
                ]
});
```

What I want to do is query this JSON array in my Objective-C code, and perform certain actions based on what's being returned, through the use of the if statement on the bottom. For example, where it says:

```
if ([result intValue] == 1){
                                                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowMatchCenterSegue" sender:self];
                                                }
```

I want to replace `result intValue` with a statement that says the value of "Number of matches" from the JSON data is equal to 1.

```
- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender
{
    if (self.itemSearch.text.length > 0) {
        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"eBayCategorySearch"
                           withParameters:@{@"item": self.itemSearch.text}
                                    block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
                                        NSLog(@"'%@'", result);

                                        NSData *returnedJSONData = result;

                                            NSError *jsonerror = nil;

                                            NSDictionary *categoryData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                                                     JSONObjectWithData:returnedJSONData
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     error:&jsonerror];

                                            if(error) { NSLog(@"JSON was malformed."); }

                                            // validation that it's a dictionary:
                                            if([categoryData isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
                                            {
                                                NSDictionary *jsonresults = categoryData;
                                                /* proceed with jsonresults */
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                NSLog(@"JSON dictionary wasn't returned.");
                                            }



                                        if (!error) {

                                            // if 1 match found clear categoryResults and top2 array
                                            if ([result intValue] == 1){
                                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowMatchCenterSegue" sender:self];
                                            }

                                            // if 2 matches found
                                            else if ([result intValue] == 2){
                                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowUserCategoryChooserSegue" sender:self];
                                                //default to selected categories criteria  -> send to matchcenter -> clear categoryResults and top2 array
                                            }

                                            // if no matches found, and 1 top category is returned
                                            else if ([result intValue] == 2) {
                                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowCriteriaSegue" sender:self];
                                            }
                                            // if no matches are found, and 2 top categories are returned
                                            else if ([result intValue] == 2) {
                                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowSearchCategoryChooserSegue" sender:self];
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }];
    }
}
```

Comment: When using a method that indirectly returns an `NSError`, Cocoa requires that you check the direct return value before using the `NSError`, not whether the error is `nil`. The error is [guaranteed](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1) to be valid if the method indicates failure, but the reverse -- that it will be `nil` for success -- is _not_ guaranteed, even if you set it to `nil` beforehand.

Comment: What is the problem that you're having? You need to know how many items are in the result dictionary? It's not at all clear what you mean by "number of matches".

Comment: If you look at the JSON I have being returned, `"Number of matches"` is one of the keys, and its value is derived from the length of the `userCategoriesMatchingTop2` array in my cloud code. In this case, I want to tell my iOS app to perform a certain action if `userCategoriesMatchingTop2.length` is equal to 1.

Comment: And what is the difficulty you're facing in achieving that?

Comment: I'm unsure of how to form the syntax that would be required to do this. I've looked into NSDictionary documentation, and it's not very clear how I would handle this particular situation.

Comment: I think it would involve the use of `valueForKey` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You can use [[jsonresults valueForKey:@"Number of matches"]intValue] , I guess userCategoriesMatchingTop2.length is gonna return a value at run time from ur back-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the response `JSON` data that you get, is an array of dictionaries within a dictionary.

To retrieve each of those values, you may use the following steps:

**Step 1:**

Separate the array of dictionaries from the result dictionary into an `NSArray` object.

```
NSArray *resultArray = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];
```

**Step 2:**

Now that you have the `resultArray`, you can extract the values that you want as follows:
Suppose you want the value of `NSNumber` object `"Number of matches"`,
You know that its the `3rd` object in the `resultArray`, so its index is `2`.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [resultArray objectAtIndex:2];
NSNumber *numberOfMatches = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Number of matches"];
```

Now you can use the `[numberOfMatches intValue]` wherever you want.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This definitely looks right and makes sense. However, when I setup my code like this and run it, the app crashes and I get this returned: http://codeshare.io/9lnvz

Comment: Please move the lines that you wrote to separate the data from the dictionary to the `if (!error) {}` block.

Comment: Also please use exception breakpoints to get the exact location of the crash.

Comment: From the [response data](http://codeshare.io/9lnvz), what I observe is that `"Top categories"` and `"User categories that match search"` are an array of numbers. So you need to set the type to `NSArray` instead of `NSNumber` for these fields.